# How do you solve $x^2 - 4 \equiv 0 \mod 21$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, quadratic-residues

There is an example in my textbook of how you solve:
$$ x^2 -4\equiv 0 \mod 21 \Leftrightarrow  x^2-4\equiv 0 \mod 3 \times 7$$
and then 2 congruences can be formed out of this equation if:
$$x^2-4\equiv0 \mod 3 \\ x^2-4 \equiv 0 \mod 7$$
and from these 2 congruences result 2 more congruences, for each:
$$x - 2 \equiv 0 \mod 3 \Rightarrow x_1 = 2\\ x + 2 \equiv 0 \mod 3 \Rightarrow x_2 = 1\\ x - 2 \equiv 0 \mod 7 \Rightarrow x_3 = 2\\ x + 2\equiv 0 \mod 7 \Rightarrow x_4 = 5$$

and then 4 systems of linear congruences are formed:
$$\begin{cases} x \equiv 2 \mod 3 \\ x \equiv 2 \mod 7\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases} x \equiv 2 \mod 3 \\ x \equiv 5 \mod 7\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases} x \equiv 1 \mod 3 \\ x \equiv 2 \mod 7\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases} x \equiv 1 \mod 3 \\ x \equiv 5 \mod 7\end{cases}$$

What is the purpose of these systems? I already have the 4 solutions ($x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$) of the congruence. Why do I need to form these systems?

Comment: This is because there are infinite solutions. (2,1,2,5) are not the only integers that satisfy the main equation. By setting up four congruence relations you are essentially writing a general form of these solutions

Comment: You have two solutions for $\pmod3$ and two for $\pmod7$. But you need solutions for $\pmod{3\cdot7}$

Comment: Clearly $x=5$ is A solution. I'm not familiar with number theory but I from what you have written it seems that the book is trying to find all possible solutions. Since taking square root is not a "legitimate" operation, so the books reduces the problem to a linear ones which are easier to solve.

Comment: for instance if you look at the first system of equation you get $x=23$ as another solution since $23-2$ is both divisible by $3$ and $7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ‘4 solutions’  are not solutions modulo $21$, but pairs of solutions $\bmod3$ on one hand, $\bmod 7$ on the other hand.

From these pairs of solutions, you recover solutions modulo $3\times 7$ with the *Chinese remainder theorem*.

Start from the *Bézout's relation* $\;5\cdot 3-2\cdot 7=1$. Then the solution corresponding to the pair $(\color{red}1\bmod3,\color{red}5\bmod7)$, for instance, will be
$$x\equiv\color{red}5\cdot5\cdot 3-\color{red}1\cdot2\cdot 7=61\equiv19\mod 21.$$

Answer (score 2):

You need that $x^2\equiv 4\pmod{3}$ ***and*** $x^2\equiv 4\pmod{7}$. For instance, your $x_2=1$ doesn't satisfy $x_2^2\equiv 4\pmod{21}$.

You used ***or*** instead of ***and***.